# Why do (many) humans like carbonated drinks?

Tags: taste

Many/most humans like certain types of food/drink because of the psychological/physiological responses we have to consuming them. Some examples:

- We like sugar because it is very energy-rich (and is relatively scarce in nature).
- We like salt because it is one of the essential building blocks of our cells.

But why do we like drinking carbonated drinks? (Soda drinks like Cola, Fanta, Tonic, Dr. Pepper, etc. but also sparkling wine, cider, champagne) Except in some very rare, special springs, carbonated water does not occur in nature. Why do we like drinking it so much?

Comment: Effervescence is fun. Pop rocks, Fizzies, etc.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, but _why_ do we like it?

Comment: Because it's fun. Why do you like swinging when you're a kid?

Comment: @anongoodnurse That's circular reasoning. I like swinging (and still do :D) because of the adrenaline rush caused by the point of weightlessness when the swing is at its highest point, as well as the speed at which you can move forwards and backwards. I do agree with you that many preferences are mostly psychological, rather than physical (and thus a lot harder to quantify), but "it's fun because it's fun" is not an explanation at all. :)

Comment: Of course it is. I just didn't go into all the reasons it was fun. It's the condensed version.